# Android horizontal scroll position in recyclerview with inflated linear layouts lost

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a quite complex `RecyclerView` :
each item I populate my `RecyclerView` with has a `LinearLayout` inside, that I need to dynamically inflate in the "`onBindViewHolder`" method, with custom items. So it ends up being a `RecyclerView` of `linearLayouts` that have inflated items inside (vertical scroll for my `RecyclerView`, horizontal scroll for each `linearLayouts`).

When I click on an item inside one of those `LinearLayouts`, I need to place some `UI` image on it, to show that it's the current selected item. Nothing too difficult, `OnClickListener` on each inflated item, and then I set the `UI` resource. But it starts getting tricky when I need to remove the `UI` resource from the PREVIOUS selected item (there can only be one selected item).

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemChanged` makes the whole `RecyclerView` data (or row) refresh itself, recreating the dynamically inflated items in each layout (or in the row's layout), and reseting the horizontal scroll position (which I want to preserve, so that the user don't get brought back to horizontal scroll 0).

Could there be a somewhat easy solution to keep the horizontal scroll states of my `LinearLayouts` every time I `notifyDataSetChanged` my `RecyclerView`, in order to preserve them ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save horizontal scroll position, such at array or even object attribute, and scroll it on bindviewholder.

```
int[] scrollXState = new int[<data size>];
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
    scrollXState[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = 
    holder.nestedRecyclerView.getScrollX();
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

And onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   holder.nestedRecyclerView.post(() ->
holder.nestedRecyclerView.setScrollX(scrollXState[holder.getAdapterPosition()]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so with a bit of tweaking, I made it work : I created an interface that I called "onItemClicked", that has two functions "select(int position)" and "deselect()". This interface is implemented by the ViewHolder, and whenever an item is clicked, I select the item, and make the adapter deselect every single other item. By doing that, I got rid of the "notifyDataSetChanged()" that was bothering me, and it works as intended !

Your solution seems like it'd work, I didn't check the "nestedRecyclerView" to get the scroll, that could have saved me, haha.

Thank you for your fast answer though.

Comment: If you just have only selected item, you should save selected position, and just call notifyItemchanged ( just changed item ) to improve adapter's performance, instead of call notifyDataSetChanged, which rebind all item. maybe i do not understand your question clearly. By the way, your solution is another way, good luck :